# Regexextract decimal number from text with decimals

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a simple google sheets `REGEXEXTRACT` function that extracts numbers from NFL lines and over  unders.

Here's the problem:
The function

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(I3,"-*\d*.?\d+"))
```

properly extracts -13.5 from text `Line: GB -13.5`
But when I use the same function on the text `O/U: 51.5`, it incorrectly extracts 51.0

Where is my regular expression failing me?

Comment: If you are willing to change your formula you could probably also use [this very short version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65782427/1527780).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your current regex is that, as written, in the second case the leading portion of the pattern is not matching anything, and only the final `\d+` matches the integer `51` ([see the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/KAroAF/2)).  You see `51.0` in your Excel spreadsheet because the decimal component defaults to being zero.  Please use this regex pattern instead:

```regex
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

### Demo

Comment: This returned a value of .5

Comment: `REGEXEXTRACT()` will return the 1st capture group if you don't make it non-capturing.

Comment: @JvdV I intentionally left out `?:` because I assumed Excel's regex engine to be primitive and not even understand it.  I guess I was mistaken.

Comment: OP is using Google Sheets which is a little less primitive =)

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw another approach into the ring:

`=1*REGEXEXTRACT(I3,"[\d.-]+")`

`[\d.-]+` reads "Any digit or period or hyphen in any unbroken combination of one or more such characters."

The `1*` is another method of turning a number-like string into a true number.

Comment: My preferred solution. For added compatibility use [\d.,-]+ to include , separated thousands. wrap in VALUE() to convert properly to a number

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
=--REGEXEXTRACT(I3,"-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?")
```

The pattern means:

- `-?` - Optional hypen.
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group.

  - `\.\d+` - A literal dot and 1+ digitis.
  - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional.

---

Instead of `VALUE()` I used the double negative to make use of the ability of GS to turn a string that looks like a number into a number through direct calculations. The first hyphen creates a negative number which we counter with the 2nd. The same result can be achieved through `1*`.

Comment: This worked!!  Can you explain the -- in the formula ?

Comment: I'm learning a lot from this. Did you mean to put a question mark on the end of your pattern to make the decimal part optional though? It looks like it doesn't work on integers as shown, should they ever occur.

Comment: I edited the pattern as indeed it needed the question mark. Strange how I had it all ready included in my explanation underneath it. @TomSharpe. And the whole point was to have the optional decimal point in case of integers as you suggest. Thank for the extra eyes here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the shortest one would be

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(I2," .*")+0
```

[image]

**Which means:**
*`return everything after the space and turn it to a number`*

Comment: whoa, this is fantastic!